# No me carga los datos mi jtable en java swing, estoy usando listas enlazadas simples

Tags: java, java-swing, arraylist, jtable

El codigo lo veo bien pero no carga los datos en la pantalla, estoy usando listas enlazadas simples, solo puedo usar arraylist para cargarlo en la tabla, asi que copie la lista enlazada a un arraylist pero no muestra los datos.

````
public Pantalla_Simular() {
        initComponents();
        cargarTablaDatos();
        
        }
     private void cargarTablaDatos(){
     Operaciones_Vuelo de = new Operaciones_Vuelo();
         this.Datosvuelo=de.getRegistroVuelos();
         
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tblvuelo.getModel();
     
      model.setRowCount(0);
        
        for ( Nodo e : Datosvuelo) {
            //generar fila
            model.addRow(new Object[]{e.piloto
                ,e.modelo,
                e.pasajeros
                ,e.sobrecargos});  
              }
            }``` 

```public ArrayList<Nodo>getRegistroVuelos() { 
        ArrayList<Nodo> tabla = new ArrayList<Nodo>(); 
        
        Nodo aux= this.Lista;
        
       while (aux != null) {
            tabla.add(aux);
            aux = aux.siguiente;
            
        }
       return tabla;
    }```
````